# Families of Sets with Two Intersection Numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $k$ and $n$ be natural numbers. Let $I$ be a set of natural numbers. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $k$-element subsets of $\{ 1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$, $A \neq B$, implies $|A \cap B| \in I$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is called an $I$-intersecting family.

I am interested in some families of $k$-sets with $|I|=2$. The smallest (for me) interesting cases are the following.

1. $n = 49, k=13, I = \{ 1, 4\}$. Here Delsarte's linear programming bound shows $|\mathcal{F}| \leq 196$.
2. $n = 21, k=13, I = \{ 7, 9\}$. Here Delsarte's linear programming bound shows $|\mathcal{F}| \leq 105$.

In both cases I would be very happy if I could show that the linear programming bound is not tight. I tried all more general methods, which I know of, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Given F, look at the multiset G given by f-I for all f in F.  For distinct g, h in G, either g=h as sets or they are disjoint. Your parameters suggest much smaller bounds like 4 times 5 or 4 times 2.

Comment: The approach above seems so natural to me that I must be missing something.  Perhaps you can tell me what.

Comment: I do not get the expression $f-I$ at the moment. As $I$ just contains the allowed intersection sizes, it will not be my $I$. Maybe you are reading $|A \cap B| \in I$ as $A \cap B \in I$?

Comment: By the way, for the second problem I can find examples of size 63 by a (not very sophisticated) computer search. So any solution, which implies a bound less than 63, will not work.

Comment: You are right.  I missed the cardinality symbol.  Maybe constructing a partial design of a few sets, and then showing that only so many copies of that part can be present will help.

Comment: Yes, that's the only method left. My hope was/is that I missed some obvious argument such as an Oddtown theorem.